# Rails saving german price to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, currency

i want to save a price like this "199,99" as a float or decimal to the database.

i have tried to replace the "," with "." in the model with a before filter.

but the price is passed to the before filter as "199.00".

is there a way to convert that in the model class?
I know how to do this in the controller, but how can i do it in the model?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct way of doing this is keep the db value as it is, and in your view layer create a helper method to display the amount with your preferred formatting

so basic idea is, in your application helper

```
module ApplicationHelper
   #p for price, just to keep things simple
   def p(amount)
     amount.gsub(".",",")
   end
end
```

and in your view

```
<%= p(object.price) %>
```

and one more disadvantage of your approach is , if you save the price as `123,34`, you will not be able to do any calculations later.

HTH

Comment: i dont want to save the price with a comma "123,34". the user types the price in the form and i want to convert it in the model from "123,34" to 123.34  . do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use number_to_currency helper and appropriate locales

Or if you don't want to mess with locales declare separator explicitly.

```
number_to_currency(value_from_db, :unit => "$;", :separator => ".", :delimiter => " ", :format => "%u %n")
```

Comment: can i do that in the model to?

Comment: @user993460 then you should review your application and database locales.